# C# - Stop recursion inside (nested?) Foreach

Tags: c#, recursion, unity-game-engine

I am trying to search for a specific type of tiles, using a recursive method. Problem is it goes infinite. I think it's because it still call the method in the rest of the foreach, so I was wondering if any of you had an improvement/correction. Here is the code I'm using :

```
private Tiles LookForCheckedWlakable(Tiles t)
{
    if (t.IsChecked())
        return t;
    else
    {
        foreach (Tiles n in t.neighbours)
        {
            if (!n.visited)
            {
                n.visited = true;
                Tiles result = LookForCheckedWlakable(n);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT :

As people asked, here is my Tiles class (ignore Monobehaviour, it is the master class from Unity. Also, some attributes are public so I can spy on them on Unity editor. I ll change it back to private as soon as this is fixed) :

```
public class Tiles : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Tiles> neighbours = new List<Tiles>();
public int x, y;
public Boolean isWalkable = false;
public Boolean check = false;
public Boolean visited = false;

/// <summary>
/// Allow other tiles to add themselves as a neighbour of their neighbours and vice versa. Fail if they already know each other.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="t">The tiles you want to add as a neighbour.</param>
public void addNeighbour(Tiles t)
{
    if (!t.getNeighbour().Contains(this))
    {
        this.neighbours.Add(t);
        t.getNeighbour().Add(this);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the neighbours of this tiles
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A list with all of this tiles' neighbours</returns>
public List<Tiles> getNeighbour()
{
    return this.neighbours;
}
}
```

Thanks for making the remark that this code would be usable only once due to the visited not being reset, i'll change that. 
I have no idea how to check if this is "just being slow". I already have other algortihm that iterates over my map, and it does not take infinite time.

EDIT 2 :

I am trying to make a "game board" with tiles. They can be walkable, obstacles, or hole. I want to generate it randomly, but need to check that the whole graph is still connexe. I use this recursive method to find the nearest walkable tiles from an isolated tiles (I know it is isolated because I floodfill my graph from a starting point, checking them on the fly. When they're not checked, they're isolated.)

MEGA EDIT TO EXPLAIN EVERYTHING I CAN THINK OF :

Here, you can see the generated graph I have. On the left, what I have, on the right, what I want.

(I wanted to post the direct image, but apparently I need reputation...)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6chC.jpg

You can see the "isolated one". I want to pahtifnd from the isolated to the rest of the grpah. I know the rest of the graph is checked, thanks to this method (which I start from a starting tiles that I manually check) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Flood fill, aka check every walkable tiles from the starting tiles
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tiles">The starting tiles</param>
private void Floodfill(Tiles tiles)
{
    //Create queue to flood fill
    Queue<Tiles> queue = new Queue<Tiles>();
    queue.Enqueue(tiles);
    //We flood fill, aka we look for every components in the neighbours and check them.
    //Any non checkes tiles is isolated.
    while (queue.Count != 0)
    {
        Tiles t = queue.Dequeue();
        t.CheckIt();
        foreach (Tiles neighbour in t.neighbours)
        {
            if (neighbour.isWalkable && !neighbour.IsChecked())
                queue.Enqueue(neighbour);
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I look for isolated and do this :

```
void TryConnexe()
{
    //We found the spawn of the player on the left, which is a guaranteed walakable.
    Tiles start = allTiles.Find(t => t.x == 1 && t.y == 9);
    Floodfill(start);

    //Now, we look in every of our tiles.
    foreach (Tiles tiles in allTiles)
    {
        //As soon as it isn't checked, it's an isolated one.
        if (tiles.isWalkable && !tiles.IsChecked())
        {
            //this is the line that makes everything goes infinite.
            Tiles goal = LookForCheckedWlakable(tiles);
            Debug.Log("recursivity ended with : ");
            //we floodfill the remaining one, because we need to check them. Otherwise, the code will restart on a possible next tile.
            Floodfill(tiles);
            Dictionary<Tiles, Tiles> path = Pathfind(tiles, goal);
            Tiles current = path[goal];
            while (current != tiles)
            {
                current.isWalkable = true;
                current.CheckIt();
                current.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;//walkable
                goal = current;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

That's all I can think of. If you need any more explanation, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you share your class `Tiles`

Comment: @FortyTwo I look forward to `Tiles` being a struct :D

Comment: @Gusdor I don't see why the compiler would accept the `return null` if `Tiles` was a struct.

Comment: Please provide a full code example (with actual Tiles data) that shows your problem. Are you absolutely sure, that the execution is infinite rather than just being slow?

Comment: Unless your 'visited' property is getting reset somewhere, you can only run this code once.

Comment: Are you certain that it is actually going infinite?  How many tiles do you have in your "network" of tiles, and how many times is the function being called?

Comment: @grek40 Unity crash (it froze, doesn't let me do anything. Only solution is to shut it down via task manager)

Comment: Now we still need an example tile configuration that shows the problem... if I just configure two tiles to be neighbors, I suspect I won't reproduce the problem? A debugging idea: create a `HashMap<Tuple<int,int>,int>` with `Key` being the `x, y` values that you visit and `Value` being the count of visits. Fill the map at the start of function. Let the algorithm execute for some time or iteration count, then cancel it and inspect the resulting count-map. If you have high counts, then there is some kind of design problem. How many tiles do you random-generate for your tests?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/T0xfp @grek40
in this photo, you can see tiles that are green (walkable) and 2 isolated ones (The two green at the top). I know in my algorithm that they are isolated, because I floodfill my graphe (aka I check a tiles, then check every of its neghbours, and do that until no more neighbours unchecked), then every non checked tiles is an isolated one. I then need to pathfind from an isolated to a non-isolated. But to pathfind I need a "Start" and a "Goal". To have the goal, I want to use this recusive method on my start tiles, which is the isolated one. Hope that helps ^^

Comment: It doesn't really help, it just explains there's a lot going on that's not visible from your question and we don't know how / on what data you call the function in question. Due to the lack of information I don't even know why you call the 2 cells isolated instead of saying the 2 cells are the accessible area and the rest is isolated. Also, as far as the picture reveals, there are three separate green areas, not two

Comment: @grek40, hey, I made a master edit with all I can think of. If you need more, feel free to ask.

Comment: If I ever find the time to create the tile map in memory based on your image, I may be able to try reproducing your problem. It would be easier if you provide a initialization function (however, I'm already 2/3 done, I can create a connected list of tiles that form a hexagon, I just didn't yet translate the black and red tiles from your image to coordinates and I don't know why there are 3 colors of tiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the 99th look, it appears to me that you just mis-diagnosed your point of failure. I suspect your code doesn't really go infinite at `Tiles goal = LookForCheckedWlakable(tiles);`, instead, it will go infinite in the following while-loop

```
while (current != tiles)
{
    current.isWalkable = true;
    current.CheckIt();
    current.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;//walkable
    goal = current; // bad
}
```

And my crystal balls tell me, you can fix it by correcting your loop "increment":

```
while (current != tiles)
{
    current.isWalkable = true;
    current.CheckIt();
    current.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;//walkable
    current = path[current]; // better, depending on the actual result of Pathfind
}
```

If my crystal ball was wrong, continue to my original answer and start finding what you do differently.

---

See my long answer below, where I in-depth tested your `LookForCheckedWlakable` just to discover: it's likely not at fault.

---

Ok, I reproduced your tiles configuration to the best of my knowledge and tried to reproduce your problem (with just some minor differences in variable/function names).

Result: the code is running, no endless execution occurs. Feel free to test my code and use it as reference to understand what you did wrong in your actual code.

As far as I can tell, you missed some crucial detail for your question and because you don't know what you missed, I wrote this answer so you have a starting point.

```
public class Tiles
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public bool IsWalkable { get; set; }

    public bool Visited { get; set; }

    private List<Tiles> _neighbours = new List<Tiles>();

    public IEnumerable<Tiles> GetNeighbours()
    {
        return _neighbours;
    }

    public void AddNeighbour(Tiles neighbour)
    {
        if (!_neighbours.Contains(neighbour))
        {
            _neighbours.Add(neighbour);
            neighbour._neighbours.Add(this);
        }
    }
}

public static class TileSolver
{
    // just run this to emulate your example
    public static void RunExample()
    {
        var t1 = GenerateTilePositions();
        var t2 = GenerateTiles(t1);

        var start = t2.First(x => x.X == 0 && x.Y == 8);

        Floodfill(start);

        //Now, we look in every of our tiles.
        foreach (Tiles tile in t2)
        {
            //As soon as it isn't checked, it's an isolated one.
            if (tile.IsWalkable && !tile.IsChecked)
            {
                //this is the line that makes everything goes infinite.
                Tiles goal = LookForCheckedWlakable(tile);

                //we floodfill the remaining one, because we need to check them. Otherwise, the code will restart on a possible next tile.
                Floodfill(tile);

                // no need to for the rest, since you claim LookForCheckedWlakable is at fault
                // and you don't provide code for Pathfind and GetComponentInChildren 
            }
        }
    }

    private static Tiles LookForCheckedWlakable(Tiles t)
    {
        if (t.IsChecked)
            return t;
        else
        {
            foreach (Tiles n in t.GetNeighbours())
            {
                if (!n.Visited)
                {
                    n.Visited = true;
                    Tiles result = LookForCheckedWlakable(n);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void Floodfill(Tiles tiles)
    {
        //Create queue to flood fill
        Queue<Tiles> queue = new Queue<Tiles>();
        queue.Enqueue(tiles);
        //We flood fill, aka we look for every components in the neighbours and check them.
        //Any non checkes tiles is isolated.
        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            Tiles t = queue.Dequeue();
            t.IsChecked = true;
            foreach (Tiles neighbour in t.GetNeighbours())
            {
                if (neighbour.IsWalkable && !neighbour.IsChecked)
                    queue.Enqueue(neighbour);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generate a hexagon of tile positions for the following indexing pattern:
    /// Suppose a triangle with the points: upper left, upper right, bottom center
    /// The parameter N describes the count of Tiles on the edges of the generated hexagon.
    /// The relation of triangle and hexagon is as follows:
    /// 
    ///      (N - 1, 0) (2N - 2, 0)
    ///   (0, 0) . . x x x . . (3N - 3, 0)
    ///           . x x x x .
    /// (0, N - 1) x x x x x (2N - 2, N - 1)
    ///             x x x x
    ///  (0, 2N - 2) x x x (N - 1, 2N - 2)
    ///               . .
    ///                .
    ///           (0, 3N - 3)
    /// 
    /// The indices start at (x=0, y=0) upper left of the triangle, increasing x while going to the right
    /// and increasing y while going down and half-right.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="N"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Tuple<int, int>> GenerateTilePositions()
    {
        int N = 9;
        var result = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 3 * N - 2; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3 * N - 2; y++)
            {
                if (N - 2 < x + y &&
                    x + y < 3 * N - 2 &&
                    x < 2 * N - 1 &&
                    y < 2 * N - 1)
                {
                    result.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    private static void SetNotWalkable(Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tiles> tilesDict, int x, int y)
    {
        tilesDict[Tuple.Create(x, y)].IsWalkable = false;
    }

    private static void TryAddNeighbour(Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tiles> tilesDict, Tiles item, int offsetX, int offsetY)
    {
        Tiles neighbour;
        if (tilesDict.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(item.X + offsetX, item.Y + offsetY), out neighbour))
        {
            item.AddNeighbour(neighbour);
        }
    }

    private static List<Tiles> GenerateTiles(List<Tuple<int, int>> t2)
    {
        var tilesDict = t2.ToDictionary(
            pos => pos,
            pos => new Tiles
            {
                X = pos.Item1,
                Y = pos.Item2,
                IsChecked = false,
                Visited = false,
                IsWalkable = true, // some will be changed manually
            });

        // connect neighbours
        foreach (var item in tilesDict.Values)
        {
            TryAddNeighbour(tilesDict, item, -1, 0);
            TryAddNeighbour(tilesDict, item, 1, 0);
            TryAddNeighbour(tilesDict, item, 0, -1);
            TryAddNeighbour(tilesDict, item, 0, 1);
            TryAddNeighbour(tilesDict, item, -1, 1);
            TryAddNeighbour(tilesDict, item, 1, -1);
        }

        // Unchecked Green positions after FloodFill:
        //Tuple.Create(8, 0);
        //Tuple.Create(7, 1);
        //Tuple.Create(7, 2);

        // Special positions (red, black)
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 0);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 14, 0);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 15, 0);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 16, 0);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 8, 1);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 11, 1);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 1);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 2);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 8, 2);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 2);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 14, 2);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 3);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 3);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 10, 3);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 13, 3);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 10, 4);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 4);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 13, 4);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 14, 4);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 3, 5);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 5);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 8, 5);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 5);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 5);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 15, 5);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 2, 6);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 3, 6);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 6);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 6);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 16, 6);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 1, 7);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 3, 7);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 7);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 7);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 7);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 16, 7);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 8);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 8);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 13, 8);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 0, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 1, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 8, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 10, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 12, 9);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 13, 9);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 3, 10);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 4, 10);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 8, 10);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 10, 10);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 5, 11);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 11);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 11);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 10, 11);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 4, 12);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 12);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 12);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 11, 12);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 6, 13);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 13);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 13);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 11, 13);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 0, 14);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 2, 14);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 3, 14);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 8, 14);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 9, 14);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 0, 15);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 15);

        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 0, 16);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 2, 16);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 3, 16);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 4, 16);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 5, 16);
        SetNotWalkable(tilesDict, 7, 16);

        return tilesDict.Values.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was effectivley in the while, I am sorry for all the trouble you went through to help me. I still keep your full example as it is very concise.